# Rails RSpec Routing: Testing actions in :except do NOT route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec

Fairly simple problem (I'd have thought), but I'm having some issues:

In Rails 3.1.0.rc6/RSpec 2.6.0, I'm trying to test the routing of my 'products' resource, routed like this:

```
resources :products, :except => [:edit, :update]
```

The routing for the valid actions works, but I want to ensure that the edit and update routes *are not* callable. Here's what I'm trying:

```
it "does not route to #edit" do
  lambda { get("/products/1/edit") }.should raise_error
end
```

> Failure/Error: lambda { get("/products/1/edit") }.should raise_error
>          expected Exception but nothing was raised
>        # ./spec/routing/products_routing_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels)
>   in '

...And yet, when I run

```
it "does not route to #edit" do
  get("/products/1/edit").should_not route_to("products#edit", :id => "1")
end
```

I get

> Failure/Error: get("/products/1/edit").should_not
>   route_to("products#edit", :id => "1")
>        ActionController::RoutingError:
>          No route matches "/products/1/edit"

Any idea what's going on here? I'm guessing this should be pretty simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know why the lambda would fail, but I don't think the rspec-rails dsl is intended to be used like that. Have you tried something like this?

```
{ :get => "/products/1/edit" }.should_not be_routable
```

http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs/be-routable-matcher

So you can't specify what it doesn't route to, but you can specify that it doesn't get routed.

Comment: We have a winner. Strange - I think Rails 2 used to handle "raise error" lambdas, but clearly not 3.1. Wasn't even aware of the be_routable method - many thanks.

Comment: Very useful!  Just one quick note:  the above test MUST be in /spec/routing/xxxx.rb or it will fail with an error.  You can't, for instance, have this in /spec/requests/xxxx.rb

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a fallback route? Because that would explain why no error is thrown, but indeed trying to evaluate `route_to("products#edit", :id => 1)` would raise, because the route does not exist.

Comment: Nice thought, but no. This is a bare project - literally started this afternoon. No redirects set up - at the moment it's just untouched bare scaffolded resources, rspec & cucumber.