# Rspec & Rails: how to test controller for 404 error? It gives "no route matches" error instead of 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, routes

I want to test that application responds with 404 error and have code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::UsersController do

  describe "GET new" do
    before { get :new }
    it { should respond_with(404) }
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
namespace :admin, module: :admin do
  resources :users, except: [:new, :create]
end
```

When I ran local server in production mode it really responds with 404 error, but when I run rspec test, it gives me the following:

```
1) Admin::UsersController GET new shold not be successful
   Failure/Error: get :new
   ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
     No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/users"}
   # ./spec/controllers/admin_users_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can I test this correctly?

**Updated with correct answer:**

```
describe "GET new" do
  it "should not route to new" do
    expect(get: :new).not_to be_routable
  end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing error pages in Rails with Rspec + Capybara](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996259/testing-error-pages-in-rails-with-rspec-capybara)

Comment: That does not help. I've already read that. No difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can check it with helper `{ get :new }.should_not be_routable` [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7221545/724036)

Update from comment:

Should be `expect(:get => :new).not_to be_routable`

Comment: Your version did not work either, but a little bit modified worked perfectly: `expect(:get => :new).not_to be_routable`